# Do I need to add or rule or add Redis to VNet in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis

I enabled VNet integration on an Azure App Service and now when I attempt to connect to Redis, I receive this error message. However, I can connect without issues using Another Redis Desktop Manager.

```
"No connection is available to service this operation: It was not 
possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout; IOCP: 
(Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: 
(Busy=5,Free=32762,Min=2,Max=32767), Local-CPU: n/a
```

Do I need to add a rule to the VNet to allow the connection to Redis or does Redis need to be on the same VNet?

Currently, I'm using a Standard version in Azure and looks like I would need to create a new instance with Premium.

Comment: What are the current vnet outbound rules?

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this `"No connection is available to service this operation: It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s); ConnectTimeout` error, try the following ways:

1. Downgrade `StackExchange.Redis` to `v2.1.58`
2. Use the `Primary connection string (StackExchange.Redis)` from Azure Access Keys as the parameter to `ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect()` instead of creating a `ConfigurationOptions` parameter using the Endpoint and Password separately.
3. If you are using a secure TLS connection set the `ssl=True`, `sslprotocols=tls12` in your configuration to the latest version.

You can refer to [RedisConnectionException: No connection is available to service this operation](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1120)